# How to get the text from span with scrapy

Tags: scrapy

I am trying to get the 4 next to the Shipment unit from this page: https://www.yesasia.com/global/hospital-playlist-ost-kihno-kit-album-99s-version/1090424142-0-0-0-en/info.html

I am only getting None.

```
response.xpath("//div[@class='infoContent']/table/tbody/tr[8]/td/span/text()").get()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This website uses JavaScript. You must load the JS and then you can use the selectors to extract info. There is a framework called splash that can help you do this.

Comment: Thanks, used selenium and added a wait for the page to load